# HTC Desire, Froyo - Gmail hangs when sending attachments

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, gmail

I have a HTC desire with Froyo, stock rom (Orange 2.17.61.3). I never had any problems with Gmail (version 2.3.2). However, since a couple of days when I try to send attachments (any kind, pdf, pictures, etc.) it just hangs.

The mails are in the outbox but don't get sent and Gmail doesn't synchronize anymore. If I delete the mails from the outbox, Gmail still fails to synchronize. To resurrect it I have to force stop it and clear its cache.

There is constant internet connection through WIFI and I can browse, access the net through other apps with no problems. Current space on the phone, 15.7MB internal and 55MB on the sd card.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

I've found that Android experiences random hangs and lockups when there are less than ~20MB of internal memory. In particular, I've found that on startup there will be a few force closes from the latin keyboard and the system; also the phone becomes noticeably laggy. When there are less than 10MB, the phone is so laggy that it becomes totally unusable. You might want to clean up your internal memory and see if it helps with your problem.